# How to connect ADSL router that takes RJ11 as input with cable which is RJ45

Tags: modem, interconnect

Actually i have a [Wireless N ADSL2+ 4-Port Wi-Fi Router with modem](http://www.flipkart.com/d-link-dsl-2750u-wireless-n-adsl2-4-port-wi-fi-router/p/itmd4ky52tgtbawn?pid=RTRD4KY4UNGYCZFG&ref=738d5737-4af5-4c2d-87e8-ca10ad0c371d) and it takes RJ11 as input for internet, but my Provider cable is RJ45 and i want to use wi-fi. so how could i will be able to do this.
Is it anything like rj45 to rj11 converter?
Or i have to change the router itself ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That router has an internal modem. If your providers has RJ45 cable it means that it already give you an ethernet connection, so you don't need an ADSL router, but an ethernet router (something like the Linksys WRT610N).

If you want just to go wireless and use only the WiFi access point of your device, you can connect the provider cable to one of the 4 eth ports.